Sending Email To Search Results - Great - But How Do I Delete When Copying an email
I sent an email to a bunch of people via a searchkit search results. Select All - Send Mail via CiviMail. Worked Great! Was first time we did it.
Unfortunately 5 more people needed that email too - so i am sending another mailing (the same exact one) to them and i just created a group for those people.
When i copy (duplicate) the email - there is no way to delete the old search results from the recipients list. What I can do is exclude people from the old mailing, but some staff  that received OG email want to be included in new email. (reason:there is a slight change).
Is there a way to delete the search results? Whats the reason for making it impossible to delete?

